# CardView Background color not the one I set

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am trying to make a `RecyclerView` with `CardView` elements , each item having a different color. I am using an Adapter and passing in the resource for the color.

The problem is that my elements, instead of having the color I passed in(ex: red, blue, or green), they have different shades of purple.

If I use the same code for the child Relative Layout, the colors work perfectly, but they don't fill the whole card.

This is the element of the list:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/rl_main_list_background_color"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_main_list_game_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Game"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is the adapter

```
public class GamesListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GamesListAdapter.GamesViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<GameItem> mGamesList;


    public static class GamesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView mGameName;
        public CardView mItemRelativeLayour;

        public GamesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mGameName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_main_list_game_name);
            mItemRelativeLayour = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl_main_list_background_color);
        }
    }

    public GamesListAdapter(ArrayList<GameItem> gamesList){ mGamesList = gamesList;}


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public GamesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_list_list_element, viewGroup, false);
        GamesViewHolder gamesViewHolder = new GamesViewHolder(view);
        return gamesViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GamesViewHolder gamesViewHolder, int i) {
            GameItem currentItem = mGamesList.get(i);

            gamesViewHolder.mGameName.setText(currentItem.getGameName());
            gamesViewHolder.mItemRelativeLayour.setCardBackgroundColor(currentItem.getBackgroundColor());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mGamesList.size();
    }

}
```

And this is how I populate the list

```
gamesList = new ArrayList<>();
gamesList.add(new GameItem("Truth or Dare", R.color.truthOrDareColor));
gamesList.add(new GameItem("Kings", R.color.kingsColor));
gamesList.add(new GameItem("Flip the card(Urmatoarea Carte)", R.color.flipTheCardColor));
gamesList.add(new GameItem("Most likely to", R.color.mostLikelyToColor));
gamesList.add(new GameItem("Spin the bottle", R.color.spinTheBottleColor));
gamesList.add(new GameItem("I have sex like", R.color.iHaveSexLikeColor));
gamesList.add(new GameItem("Never have I ever", R.color.neverHaveIEverColor));
```

Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Where is code??

Comment: add some codes..

Comment: use  `setCardBackgroundColor()` instead of  `setBackgroundColor()`

Comment: insert your code plz!

Comment: I added the code, I am allready using setCardBackgroundColor()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change,

```
gamesViewHolder.mItemRelativeLayour.setCardBackgroundColor(currentItem.getBackgroundColor());
```

To,

```
gamesViewHolder.mItemRelativeLayour.setCardBackgroundColor(
          ContextCompat.getColor(context, currentItem.getBackgroundColor()));
```

You are setting `Interger` ID as Color `R.color.some_color` just stores reference to your color you have to get actual color from that id.

To get Color from Reference ID you should use following,

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.some_color);
```

Happy Coding.